# How to Find the sum of one field with some condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have the two tables `tbl_Customers` and `tbl_Invoices`.

In `tbl_Invoice` table there the following columns:

```
•   InvoiceId
•   InvoiceDate
•   DueDate
•   CustomerId
•   InvoiceAmount
•   PaidAmount
•   RemainingAmout
•   PaidOrNot
```

When I generate the New Invoice, then how do I find the sum of previous not paid invoices?

My Question is that, when I print number of invoices with where clause with Invoice create Date, then how do I find the `RemainingAmount` of customers in newly printed invoice of each customer?

[image: tbl_Invoice]

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Comment: please provide a clearer view to this.. share some code.. what you have tried

Comment: I edit my question now please answer it

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the not paid amounts, then you should get all the remaiming amount of the invoices not fully paid.

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaidAmount)
FROM tbl_Invoices 
WHERE PaidAmount < InvoiceAmount 
AND CustomerId = @custID
```

You can add a condition on the CreateDate to be smaller than Today,
or perhaps adding a condition on the DueDay (whether it was due or not).

This part was not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this with a simple select like this:

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceAmount)
FROM tbl_Invoices
WHERE PaidAmount < InvoiceAmount AND  CustomerId = @custID
```